# jq special characters in nested keys

Tags: syntax, key, jq, abbreviation

I have a json similar to the following:

```
{
    "_source" : {
        "index-pattern" : {
            "fields" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify fields, but chaining the . identity operator, such as `'jq ._source.["index-pattern"].fields`' produces the following error:

```
'._source.["index-pattern"]
         ^
1 compile error'
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could write:

```
._source | .["index-pattern"].fields
```

or even:

```
._source["index-pattern"].fields
```

Explanation: if "x" and "y" are alphanumeric strings that begin with an alphabetic character (where "alphabetic" includes "_") then `.x | .y` can be abbreviated to `.x.y`.

There are several other circumstances when `E | F` can be abbreviated, e.g. `E | .[]` can often be abbreviated to `E[]`.

However, the general rule is:

> If an abbreviated form does not work, don't use it.